# Почему неверно вешаются события?

Tags: javascript, json, циклы, события

Всем доброго времени суток. Есть задание: Отобразить список сообщений. Сообщение имеет следующие данные отправитель, дата и время и тело сообщения. В списке отобразить дату и время и отправителя. По наведению на отправителя отобразить тело сообщения. Сообщения загрузить из файла. Все запилил, кроме пункта с наведением. По моему замыслу на каждый элемент с именем вешается функция, которая добавляет или убирает класс .visible на соответствующий элемент с сообщением. Проблема в том, что почему-то в toggleMessage(i) передается i=3. Не понимаю, почему так и как заставить это работать должным образом.

```
 function toggleMessage (counter) {
    messages[counter].classList.toggle("visible");
}
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    names[i].onmouseover = function(){ toggleMessage(i) };
    names[i].onmouseout = function(){ toggleMessage(i) };
}
```

Полный код тут: https://jsfiddle.net/x6rf5bq8/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что на момент выполнения `toggleMessage(i)` цикл закончился и `i` равна максимальному значению - `names.length`. Надо создать замыкание:

```
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)(function(i) {
    names[i].onmouseover = function(){ toggleMessage(i) };
    names[i].onmouseout = function(){ toggleMessage(i) };
}(i));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и пояснение.

Comment: @7keys вот аналогичный вопрос с кучей подробных ответов: https://toster.ru/q/61244, а после того, как придет понимание "почему", можно разобраться с замыканиями: https://learn.javascript.ru/functions-closures